# No return value from C++ DLL using C#

Tags: c#, com, pinvoke

Using a console application, I'm making use of a c++ com dll to call a function.

I have added the registered DLL as a reference for the project and then I am instantiating the object and calling the function. (I should note that I'm not using pinvoke as some other people seem to be)

I should be getting a string back as a result but I am just getting an empty string. The only way I can get any form of output is by enabling debugging for unmanaged code and from that I can see that it is executing correctly and returning a result.

I have had a search around stackoverflow and a few other sites and can't quite find anything that matches this. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how I can get it to return a value?

**EDIT**: As requested, here is the code -

```
COMMODCHECKLib.Modcheck mod = new COMMODCHECKLib.Modcheck();
string output = mod.check("123456");
```

Comment: please include your code

Comment: Is the expected return type a std::string or a pointer to a null terminated character array?

Comment: @DuncanACoulter the return type should be a string

Comment: Have you tried using a StringBuilder rather than a string? It seems to do better for interop strings.

Comment: @Nanhydrin As part of my grasping at straws process I did try string builder as well

Comment: Look on your computer for OLE/COM Object viewer, it is an old utility of VisualStudio, with that utility choose File/OpenTypeLib and browse for your com dll, open it, and post the signature of the check function.

Comment: Your code is 95% functional.  It can find the COM server DLL, load it correctly, create the COM object fine, actually make the call, not trigger a failure return code or AccessViolation, actually get a string object back, not just a null or garbage.  Leaving only one possible decent explanation: the method actually returned an empty string.

Comment: @HansPassant that explanation seems pretty reasonable... As the information I need is being output to the console window when I debug - is there a way to get that information?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  If you are convinced that getting an empty string back is improper behavior then ask for help from the COM server author or vendor.  Send him a small repro project so they can troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: Well it seems that the documentation for the DLL was incorrect and gave the check function as the one I needed but infact there was a function called checkAllocate which is the one I needed to use. Apologies guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that the documentation for the DLL was incorrect and gave the **check** function as the one I needed but infact there was a function called **checkAllocate** which is the one I needed to use. Apologies guys - many thanks for your time and efforts

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to first check, if the problem is within the C# code or the COM library. For that, you can use e.g. a VB-Script file (.vbs) like

```
(test.vbs)
Set mod = CreateObject("COMMODCHECKLib.ModCheck")
WScript.echo(mod.check("123456"))
```

Just run this script from the command line (entering `test.vbs`).

If this gives the desired output, you know at least, that the problem lies on the C# side.